# How do I stop Kitty from doing naughty AutoRelogin after resuming from Windows Sleep? I recall my Putty didn't do this. Where is password cached?

Tags: windows-7, ssh, putty, sleep, kitty

I recently switched from Putty to Kitty (on windows7) and now I notice that after Windows Resumes from Standby/Sleep that it Automatically logs me in again.
I see in the SSH kitty shell window:

```
Using username "myusername".
myusername@myip's password:
Send automatic password
```

I have configured KITTY to use files instead of Windows Registry and am using the kitty_portable.exe binary. I have logging enabled but I always have "OMIT known password fields" CHECKED. So I would like to know WHERE is my PASSWORD being CACHED? And how can I disable this feature so that my password is no longer cached? Under Connection->DATA there is nothing set for Auto-login username and when username is not specified its set to PROMPT. Auto-login password is also NOT set. So would appreciate any help to disable password caching.

Comment: "[KiTTY is a fork of the original PuTTY software, with loads of new features including a portable version that saves all of your sessions and settings into an INI file in the same folder.](https://lifehacker.com/5541871/kitty-adds-session-saving-portability-and-more-to-putty)"

Comment: I'm running with the only thing in Kitty.ini is savemode=dir and I don't see any passwords or password hashes inside any of the session files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable password auto saving.
Add these lines to your kitty.ini configuration file (it should in the same directory where your kitty.exe is):

```
[KiTTY]
userpasssshnosave=yes
```

Comment: This works for me, but note that you will need to clear any existing password out of Connection->Data. With this option set, it'll stop saving future password.

Comment: Thanks, just noticed your answer, this works, in addition how can I prevent it from even attempting a reconnect? Now it tries to reconnect and prompts for user etc.